# Center a left aligned heading tag in a container div

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm looking for a way to center a left aligned text in a container div. Because the title is split into multiple lines, the width of the h1 is larger than the text itself. Therefore the text isn't placed in the middle. I can add a tailwind class like `max-w-md` which will set the width of the title to a fixed width and place the text in the middle of the div but it's incorrect. The maximum width is set on a block and I want the width of the title block to be the width of the widest line.

I've made a demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/ME3TXQXZ3M

**Current code**

```
<div class="min-w-screen flex h-full min-h-screen w-full flex-row-reverse bg-black">
  <div class="flex items-center justify-center bg-black p-4 lg:w-1/2 lg:p-10">
    <div class="text-left">
      <h1 class="text-balance font-sans text-6xl text-white">
        This is a long title so it breaks into another line. <br />
        This is another line.
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-white lg:w-1/2">
    Container
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your logic is confusing... if you want centered text, why are you left aligning it in the first place?

Comment: @Paulie_D No, I don't want the text to be centered. I want the complete paragraph (multiple lines) to be in the center (horizontal and vertical) of the black container. So text-align: left but the bounding-box of the paragraph should be in the middle. Sorry if my explanation was confusing and I hope this clarifies my question

Comment: @Thore for that you would give the Paragraph a max-width and then center it vertically in the black container by useing eg. `display: flex; justify-content: center;` on the black container. Sorry I don't know the tailwind classes for this action but you'll figure it out.

Comment: @TimGabrikowski I want to avoid this method. I will explain why with an example: The black container is 800px. The max-width of the paragraph is set to 500px which means that the left and right side of the paragraph will have 150px space on each side. The paragraphs has a simple sentence of text with some long words which will break down the sentence into three lines. The widest line is only 300px wide. The paragraph container is set to a max width of 500px. The container will be placed in the middle of the container div but the text will visually not be in the middle. (1/2)

Comment: @TimGabrikowski So I'm looking for a way to set the width of the paragraph equal to the width of the widest line of the paragraph. I can't hardcode this because the text will be translated to multiple languages and will have a different width for each language. (2)

Comment: @Thore you can still use this approach by setting the width of the text-container to `auto` because this in combination with the flexbox around it will center the container and shrink it to the minimal required width.